# Toggle between borders of a image and remove borders of other existing images

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Context

I want to select only one image and remove borders of other existing images

Now many images can be selected like that:

[image]

I want help on select and deselecting single images.

## My code

```
function clickpick(item) {

    for ( var i = 5; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        
        document.images[i].onclick = function() {
        
        if (this.style.borderWidth == '5px') {
            selectpic = '';
            $("#display-frame").find("*").css("border", "0");
        } else {
            this.style.border = '5px solid blue';
            selectpic = $(item).attr("url");
        }

    };
}
```

Images are auto generated

## Html

```
<div class="mainpic"><img src="';path+=file.filepath+'" class="uploader-thumb-img" style="width: 108px; height: 120px; top: 0px; left: 0px; "/></div>
```

update:
i want to select the url of the image sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Im not quite sure what your asking? Can you please show us the html structure of your images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Using jQuery [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function.

**CSS** :

```css
img { border: 0; }
img.highlight { border: 5px solid blue; }
```

**JavaScript** :

```javascript
var url;

$('img').click(function (e) {
    $('img.highlight').not(e.target).removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    url = $(this).attr('href');
});​
```

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/7FAjD/2

Comment: Why the e.target, why not $(this) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have only one selected image at once, you can try something like:

```
var $images = $('img');

$images.click(function () {
    $images.removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: You can deselect the selected image ([demo with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/7FAjD/3/)).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try some like this:

```
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200&text=5" onclick="clickpick(this)" />
```

JS:

```
function clickpick(item) {

        if (item.style.borderWidth == '5px') {
            item.style.border = '2px solid red';
        } else {
            item.style.border = '5px solid blue';
        }

}
```

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/VchSE/2/) updated.

Comment: i have already done this !! it allows selection of multiple images !which i dont want i just want to select single image!! and select the url of the image

Comment: ya thats what i want !! but i want to select only images inside div called gallery this selects all the images in the page