# My jquery code is working in google chrome console not after saving it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have to select and deselect images and Jquery my code is working fine in Google developer console but not after i save it in my file.

This work in chrome developer console not when i have it in my code

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhtet.png)

This was the last question which i asked it is related to this[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648786/toggle-between-borders-of-a-image-and-remove-borders-of-other-existing-images/11649003#comment15462371_11649003)

**mycode**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var selectpic;
        $('img').click(function () {
             $('img.highlight').not(this).removeClass('highlight');
             $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
             selectpic = $(this).attr('src');
            });
        });
```

This is actually inside a popup div.

**main** window which calls the above popup

```
    function showImageUploadDialog(event) {
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").show();
    cdDiv();
    $('#gallery').hide();
    $('#upload_popup').dialog({
        height : 'auto',
        width : '848px',
        modal : 'true',
        top : '58px',
        left : '559px',
        resizable : 'false',
        dialogClass : 'pop_up'
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();

}
```

I think it should be made global,And  I don't know how to make it.

Comment: **WHAT? I DID NOT HEAR YOU, THE BOLD HEADER TEXT WAS SO LOUD**.

Comment: @ubercooluk cddiv is a function which hides the gallery  function cdDiv() {$("#gallery").hide();$("#choose-display-frame").show();}

Comment: i cant run the script in my code !! there is no error !! but when i try it google console it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked after updating to the latest version of jquery!!